# How to fix errors with UAC_AsUser_ExecShell in NSIS 3?

Tags: windows, nsis, uac

Trying to use an NSI script that works with 2.46 Unicode, in the new version 3, this line:

```
!insertmacro UAC_AsUser_ExecShell '' '$INSTDIR\test.exe' '--openbrowser' '' SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

produces the following error:

```
!undef: "_UAC_ParseDefineFlags_orin_f2" not defined!
Error in macro _UAC_ParseDefineFlags_orin on macroline 12
Error in macro _UAC_ParseDefineFlags_Begin on macroline 6
Error in macro _UAC_ParseDefineFlagsToInt on macroline 1
Error in macro UAC_AsUser_Call on macroline 5
Error in macro UAC_AsUser_ExecShell on macroline 11
Error in script "c:\my.nsi" on line 308 -- aborting creation process
```

[There is a similar, unanswered question](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Talk:UAC_plug-in#UAC_AsUser.2A_error), back from a year ago.

**My question:**

How to use the [UAC plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in) with NSIS 3?

Comment: Probably, this is an easy question for @Anders.

Comment: The short answer is, don't use this plug-in.

Comment: Zut alors! Thanks for your reply. Probably there is no NSIS-3-built-in way of doing something like the plug-in?

Comment: The plug-in has never been tested with v3 but I don't see why you can't make it work, probably just a small bug in the .nsh. I'll try to take a look at it tonight...

Comment: That would be incredible helpful, thanks a lot, @Anders. My best christmas present .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UAC plug-in v0.2.4c (20150526) from the wiki I can't reproduce your error with a simple clone of UAC_Basic.nsi in NSIS v3.01:

```
Unicode true
!addplugindir ".\plugins\x86-unicode" ; Only required if you have not copied the .dll

!define S_NAME "UAC minimal test ${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}"

Name "${S_NAME}"
OutFile "${S_NAME}.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel user ; << Required, you cannot use admin!
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\${S_NAME}"


!include UAC.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh

!macro Init thing
uac_tryagain:
!insertmacro UAC_RunElevated
${Switch} $0
${Case} 0
    ${IfThen} $1 = 1 ${|} Quit ${|} ;we are the outer process, the inner process has done its work, we are done
    ${IfThen} $3 <> 0 ${|} ${Break} ${|} ;we are admin, let the show go on
    ${If} $1 = 3 ;RunAs completed successfully, but with a non-admin user
        MessageBox mb_YesNo|mb_IconExclamation|mb_TopMost|mb_SetForeground "This ${thing} requires admin privileges, try again" /SD IDNO IDYES uac_tryagain IDNO 0
    ${EndIf}
    ;fall-through and die
${Case} 1223
    MessageBox mb_IconStop|mb_TopMost|mb_SetForeground "This ${thing} requires admin privileges, aborting!"
    Quit
${Case} 1062
    MessageBox mb_IconStop|mb_TopMost|mb_SetForeground "Logon service not running, aborting!"
    Quit
${Default}
    MessageBox mb_IconStop|mb_TopMost|mb_SetForeground "Unable to elevate , error $0"
    Quit
${EndSwitch}

SetShellVarContext all
!macroend

Function .onInit
!insertmacro Init "installer"
FunctionEnd


!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION PageFinishRun
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
SectionEnd


Function PageFinishRun
!insertmacro UAC_AsUser_ExecShell '' '$WinDir\notepad.exe' '--openbrowser' '' SW_SHOWNORMAL
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: That `Unicode true` looks new to me. Probably I have to read more about migrating my scripts from NSIS 2 to 3.

Answer (score -1):

Digging an old thread:

I had the same problem, the UAC plugin on wiki has a small change compared to the version I was using with NSIS 2.x.

That small change fixed the issue

Comment: So which change was it?